# Save the data frame generated at each iteration in a list

Tags: r, list, save, dataframe

I am currently working with an RFID reader that is controlled with a web-based software in Java and PHP.
The software provides the option to control the reader through REST request. In my case, I'm making a function that requests to change the read power consecutively; whenever a request, thereupon parsing the XML where you have stored items is detected.
Every time parsing the XML, I keep the values ​​in a data frame. My problem is:
In each iteration of the "for" loop I get a data frame. I want to save the data frame into a list, but this way are not saved correctly. What do I wrong with the function?

```
if(init_power_value!="NULL" && end_power_value!="NULL"){
    if(init_power_value > end_power_value){
      aux1<-end_power_value
      end_power_value<-init_power_value
      init_power_value<-aux1
    }
    inventory_DF_List<-list()
    for(i in seq(init_power_value, end_power_value, 0.5)){
      response<-REST_GET_START_DEVICE(DF_device_value)
      REST_PUT_POWER_DEVICE(DF_device_value,as.character(i))
      response<-REST_GET_START_DEVICE(DF_device_value)

      DF_READER_CONFIGURATION<-PARSE_READER_CONFIGURATION(DF_device_value)

      DF_inventory_items_List<-PARSE_INVENTORY_items(DF_device_value)
      inventory_DF_List[[i]]<-DF_inventory_items_List
    }
  }
```

thank you very much

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue is here without knowing what all these functions do. Other than making the list, have you tested the rest of this to see if it is working?

Comment: This is exactly curious, I tested each function separately, and each gives the results correctly. The problem is when stored in the list. For example I made a 9 execution iterations, ie 27 to 31 with an increase of 0.5, and in the list there are 31 saved positions. I do not understand why. I can upload the results of each function and the full list if you want.

Comment: I think the problem is that the value of "i" can be float, not just int, as it can take values ​​as 27.5; 28.5; etc. Is there any way you can save the data frames generated if the "i" takes these values​​?

Comment: I've realized one thing, my "for" is as follows: for(i in seq(init_power_value, end_power_value, 0.5)) and if I look at the values taken by the "i" variable for, get this:
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

[[27]]
[1] 27.5

[[28]]
[1] 28.5

[[29]]
[1] 29.5

[[30]]
[1] 30.5

[[31]]
[1] 31
Is there any way that the variable "i" take the values correctly?: 
27.0 27.5 28.0 28.5 29.0 29.5 30.0 30.5 31.0

Answer (score 1):

Good catch on your own question - the i in the for loop must be an integer. Try putting the `inital_power` to `end_power` sequence in its own vector (I called it `X`)and use `seq_along` to do the integer in your for loop like so:

```
inventory_DF_List<-list()

X<-seq(init_power_value, end_power_value, 0.5)

for(i in seq_along(X)){
  response<-REST_GET_START_DEVICE(DF_device_value)
  REST_PUT_POWER_DEVICE(DF_device_value,as.character(i))
  response<-REST_GET_START_DEVICE(DF_device_value)

  DF_READER_CONFIGURATION<-PARSE_READER_CONFIGURATION(DF_device_value)

  DF_inventory_items_List<-PARSE_INVENTORY_items(DF_device_value)
  inventory_DF_List[[i]]<-DF_inventory_items_List
}
```

}

I don't know what you want in `REST_PUT_POWER_DEVICE(DF_device_value,as.character(i))`. If you want the integer, use `i`, but if you want the number from the sequenced use `X[i]`.